# Error displaying the error page: Application Instantiation Error: Failed to start the session

Tags: joomla, php-7.3

I'm getting the white screen of death on my joomla site. I am using php7.3.

I have added this to my htaccess file

```
# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# Set the “ea-php70” package as the default “PHP” programming language.
<IfModule mime_module>
AddType application/x-httpd-ea-php70 .php .php7 .phtml
</IfModule>
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
```

My hopes were that it would solve this issue, but it did not. On the frontend of my site, visitors see a white screen only. On the administrative side of my site, I am seeing this error message.

> Warning: session_start(): Failed to read session data: user (path: /var/cpanel/php/sessions/ea-php73) in /home2/webwiza2/public_html/libraries/joomla/session/handler/native.php on line 260
>   Error displaying the error page: Application Instantiation Error: Failed to start the session

I reviewed the path identified as "/var/cpanel/php/sessions/ea-php73" and the php directory level doesn't exist; not sure why the native.php would reference a directory that doesn't exist. I have my hidden files showing. In other words when I go to the /var/cpanel/ directory I only see one folder and it is not 'php.'

Comment: You aren't getting a lot of love here.  You might try at [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.

Comment: Thanks @mickmackusa I rolled back my Joomla and re-installed; updated my ini & htaccess files with the appropriate version references and all went well after that.

Comment: You mustn't answer your own question via comment.  Please post your resolution as an answer and then accept your own answer.  It is important to never abandon a question.  Please join JSE so that you can engage with that community in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I rolled back my Joomla to the previous version and re-installed; updated my ini & htaccess files with the appropriate version references and all went well after that.